# Is there a limit on amount of storage capacity a single physical machine can have?

Tags: storage

I was reading about hadoop and I got stuck in this line,
"When a dataset outgrows the storage capacity of a single physical machine, it becomes necessary to partition it across a number of separate machines."

So is there a limitation on amount of storage capacity a single physical machine can have ? I think this question falls in 'Computer Architecture', but I haven't read this subject and I am curious to know why is there a limitation. Why can't 1 physical machine potentially has 1 petabyte of data ?

Comment: I just did some googling and this answer on stackexchange seems to cover the theoretical part pretty well
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33561

Answer (score 5):

The amount of storage you can directly attach to a server is in practice usually limited only by the size of your wallet.

Typically when you need very much storage for a single server, most organisations tend to go towards SAN/network attached storage with dedicated storage arrays and controllers, rather than direct attached storage. Those can scale up beyond your 1 petabyte.

When you consider direct attached storage the technical limits for a single server are capped by:

- the number of disk connectors (i.e. the SAS/SATA ports) on the motherboard
- the number of additional storage controllers you can fit into the motherboard (PCIe sockets) and the number of devices they can each address (high end SAS controllers can address up to 256 devices each)
- the number of internal disk bays you can fill.
- the number of external drive trays you can attach and fill
- the sizes of disk drives

(Of course beyond a certain point you won't get any additional performance by adding more capacity, so there is a certain cost-benefit cut off point when scaling up is no longer as efficient as scaling out)

Answer (score 2):

Nearly all kinds of current storage protocols can offer virtually unlimited storage. The physical size might quickly exceed a single server's case capacity but you can extend the physical installation to additional rack shelves or even complete racks. The magic word is SAN (storage area network).

- SAS can use expanders to access 16 thousand physical drives (possibly more) or logical drives (see LUN below).
- Fibre Channel can use switches to access 16 million physical drives or LUNs; each LUN can consist of a large number of drives.
- iSCSI practically supports 16 million targets (private 10.0.0.0/8 network) each consisting of 256 LUNs, each in turn consisting of a large number of drives. You could also use the entire IPv4 address range for 4 billion targets or completely ridiculous numbers using IPv6 (340 undecillion or 3,4*10<sup>38</sup>).
- Even SATA can be used with port multipliers for 15 drives *per port* and you can add controllers to get a lot of ports.

It's just a question of budget to buy and connect 1 petabyte of storage. Or 10 petabyte. Or 100. Or ...

However, you don't usually hook up that much storage to a single node. Due to availability and scalability concerns, large storage capacities are routinely shared between a large number of nodes or VMs. All current enterprise storage technologies allow sharing, and the distinction between direct-attached storage and network storage is more one of implementation rather than technology.